# Apache is pointing to the wrong version of PHP

Tags: php, apache

I am on Mac OS X Lion and command `php -v` returns

```
PHP 5.4.4 (cli) (built: Jun 30 2012 16:45:58)
```

On my local server (localhost), `phpinfo` gives me:

```
PHP Version 5.3.10
```

Could you please help me, I need php 5.4 to install Symfony2.

Comment: A mon avis, [tu devrais soutenir ça](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12692/stack-overflow-in-french?referrer=adVDNkMqm5jZeiYutxUqXw2). Mais ici c'est en Anglais.

Comment: Translation:  I am on MacOSX Lion and the command php -v gives the output `PHP 5.4.4 (cli) (built: Jun 30 2012 16:45:58)`, phpinfo on my localhost gives `PHP Version 5.3.10`  Can anyone help since I need 5.4 to install Symfony2  Thanks in advance

Comment: Just because it's written in french does not mean it deserves downvotes.  It is a perfectly valid question written in perfectly acceptable French.

Comment: I added English translation for those not familiar with French.

Comment: This question may be better suited for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: What is your question? Do you need to upgrade the PHP version on your local server? Is that the same machine? Are you using MAMP or something?

Comment: Check install paths for both I think you have 2 different installs of php.
Vérifiez l'emplacement d'installation pour les deux je pense que vous avez 2 installations différentes

Comment: Yes I have 2 different installs of php. How can I tell apache to use the one I want ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Apache installation has these two lines in the httpd.conf file:

```
PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files/PHP"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

Make sure that the directory in these Apache lines is the directory of the version of PHP you want.

You'll have to stop and restart Apache after you make changes to the httpd.conf file.

Comment: I don't have PHPIniDir in my httpd.conf
I've try to add it with de path /usr/local/bin/php which is de path of my php (which php). I've restarted apache but still same problem.

What I want is apache to use php5.4 instead of using php5.3

Comment: I don't know how you could have 2 versions of PHP on your Mac, unless they live in different directories.

Comment: I do, I know where is the php5.4 but I have no Idea where is de php 5.3

Comment: Sorry, I use Windows and am not familiar with Macs.